# Unwanted P.I. Surveillance

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

We have had our Internet taken over by a P.I. It appears that there are two of our Belkin networks. One is real, and one is a shadow of the other. When we unplug our wireless, another with the exact same name accepts us in. Please help.

Comment: Try changing your WPA key. Your devices shouldn't be connecting to the other network unless it has the exact same security settings and password as your wireless router.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you explain a little more about your situation? Couldn't you just change your wireless network to another name (SSID)?

Comment: If it connects to the other that means your wireless is unprotected?

Comment: If it were me I'd turn off my WIFI connection for a while and use a tool (like Wifi Analyser) to track where the fantom AP is based on signal strength.  I'd then get law enforcement envolved - there must be laws against it.   Another useful channel might be to find the IP address associated with the phantom Internet connection using whatismyip.com as a starting point, and getting law enforcement to take down the culprit.  (Actually I have more fitting ideas, but It would be inappropriate to expound them on this site - but think along the lines of turning the tables on him !!)

Comment: There are no laws in the US that prevent this. You have the responsibility to protect your own wireless and your connection (such as encrypting the connection). This happens at airport all the time, and it is your fault of connecting to the "Shadow" wireless.

Comment: @MarkLopez Where does it say this is about the US?

Comment: @Michael Kjörling The lack of laws was my point; however, the difficulty to find the culprit and prove that they are guilty while staying within the bonds of the amendments would be difficult. Thus, unlikely to be pursued in court.

Answer (score 1):

On most routers (also called a wireless) changing both the SSID and the MAC address is possible. This would also make your access point completely different than the "Shadow" access point (also called wireless). Consult your wireless documentation on how to do this. 
(I recommend this also because changing your SSID will prevent a couple of known security flaws from compromising your network)

Also adding a WPA2 key (encrypting your wireless) will also prevent your computer from connecting to the "Shadow" access point. This is a built in security feature of WPA2. Changing/adding a WPA2 key will prevent the "Shadow" wireless from shadowing YOUR wireless.

Answer (score -1):

Whilst you have not said which model your Belkin device is I would agree with others here about changing the name, however I would strongly recommend you select to HIDE YOUR SSID which mean that they will not know your new network name. YOu can get more information from Belkin here http://www.belkin.com/us/support-article?rnId=6902

IMHO a more critial issue should be WHAT where there intentions in doing this ? Was it to just use your internet ? Or was it to capature your wireless clients data ? At the very least I would take this time to change all your systems and website passwords ( remember to warn your users as weel ).

Comment: security by obscurity is bad advice. hiding ssid doesn't help.

Comment: Hiding your SSID is bad advice - it can be found easily enough when your computer broadcasts its connection attempt.